# Incrementar os intervalos de 30 minutos entre duas datas

Tags: sql, oracle

```
 (SELECT
entrada,saida,NR_CIRURGIA,
to_char((((entrada+0.0416667)-0.0208333)+(rownum*0.0208333)),'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') dt_inicial,
 to_char(((((entrada+0.0416667)-0.0208333)+(rownum)*0.0208333)+0.0208333),'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')dt_final
from
(SELECT 
b.dt_registro entrada, c.dt_registro saida,C.* FROM (select 
  a.* 
  from  
  tasy.EVENTO_CIRURGIA_PACIENTE a
  where 
  NR_SEQ_EVENTO  = 11) b,  (select 
  a.* 
  from 
  tasy.EVENTO_CIRURGIA_PACIENTE a
  where
  NR_SEQ_EVENTO  = 9) c
  where b.nr_cirurgia = c.nr_cirurgia
  and c.nr_cirurgia = 92837
  and b.dt_registro between to_date(:dt_inicial) and to_date(:dt_final)+86399/86400) 
  e   
  where 1=1   
connect by level <= ceil(trunc(((saida- (entrada+0.0416667))*24)*2)));
```

Fiz essa consulta, retorna o resultado correto quando faço a restrição pelo numero da cirurgia,
quando tiro o número, fica um resultado infinito.

Resultado correto quando restrito por cirurgia

```
02/04/22    02/04/22    92837   02/04/2022 19:50:00 02/04/2022 20:20:00
02/04/22    02/04/22    92837   02/04/2022 20:20:00 02/04/2022 20:50:00
02/04/22    02/04/22    92837   02/04/2022 20:50:00 02/04/2022 21:20:00
02/04/22    02/04/22    92837   02/04/2022 21:20:00 02/04/2022 21:50:00
02/04/22    02/04/22    92837   02/04/2022 21:50:00 02/04/2022 22:20:00
```

Comment: "fica um resultado infinito" ... ¡¿!?

Comment: Sim, desse resultado acima pra esse código, não retorna as 5 linhas. quando tento rodar o contador ele até trava.

Comment: Sem filtro vai listar para todas as cirurgias o que pode demorar. Tentou com umas 3 ou 4 com um IN ? algo como and c.nr_cirurgia in (92837,123456,78907..)

Comment: Tenho que pegar por intervalo inicial e final. Esse exemplo acima. nesse periodo retorna linhas infinitas.

Comment: Quase impossível sem ver os dados , nestes casos eu faço uma versão "limpa" da query , analitica e vejo se acho o erro. Mas creio que não seja erro e sim muitos dados.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema com SQL abaixo:

```
 (SELECT
entrada,saida,NR_CIRURGIA,
       (((entrada+0.0416667)-0.0208333)+(row_number() over (partition by nr_cirurgia order by entrada))*0.0208333) dt_inicial,
       ((((entrada+0.0416667)-0.0208333)+(row_number() over (partition by nr_cirurgia order by entrada))*0.0208333)+0.0208333)dt_final
from
(SELECT 
b.dt_registro entrada, c.dt_registro saida,C.* FROM (select 
  a.* 
  from  
  tasy.EVENTO_CIRURGIA_PACIENTE a
  where 
  NR_SEQ_EVENTO  = 11
and IE_SITUACAO = 'A'
  ) b,  (select 
  a.* 
  from 
  tasy.EVENTO_CIRURGIA_PACIENTE a
  where
  NR_SEQ_EVENTO  = 9
 and IE_SITUACAO = 'A'
  ) c
  where b.nr_cirurgia = c.nr_cirurgia
  and (c.dt_registro - b.dt_registro)*60*24 >= 60
  and b.dt_registro between to_date(:dt_inicial) and to_date(:dt_final)+86399/86400) 
  e    cross join
   table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
                        connect by level <= trunc(((SAIDA-(ENTRADA+0.0416667))*24)*2)  ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
  where 1=1  
)
```

Answer (score -3):

Olá,
Com postgresql podes fazer o seguinte

```
SELECT generate_series('01/01/2022'::DATE, '01/02/2022'::DATE, '30 minutes'::INTERVAL);
```

Este exemplo acima irá gerar registros com intervalor de 30 minutos entre as datas passadas nos parâmetros 1 e 2;